# cordova serve through cli not working

Tags: cordova

Has anyone had issues using the built in http server in Cordova? As of `cordova@6.5.0` I can't seem to get `cordova serve` to spin up. I'm using `cordova@6.5.0`, `cordova-browser@4.1.0`, and `node@6.2.2` This is what I get after running `cordova serve -d`

```
No scripts found for hook "before_serve".
Executing script found in config.xml for hook "before_prepare":        increment_build_number.js
Checking config.xml for saved platforms that haven't been added to the project
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been installed in browser platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in  browser platform. Continuing...
Checking for any plugins added to the project that have not been  installed in ios platform
No differences found between plugins added to project and installed in ios platform. Continuing...
Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "browser"
Generating platform-specific config.xml from defaults for iOS at   /Users/**/config.xml
Merging project's config.xml into platform-specific iOS config.xml
Merging and updating files from [www, platforms/ios/platform_www] to platforms/ios/www
Current launch storyboard undefined
Not changing launch storyboard setting.
Wrote out iOS Bundle Identifier "com.*.*" and iOS   Bundle Version "1.0.0" to   /Users/**/*-Info.plist
Set TARGETED_DEVICE_FAMILY to "1".
Set IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET to "9.3".
```

Comment: As far as i could see, i dont find any error in the trace.  Everything looks more of an info in the trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be fixed for me as of upgrading `node@7.6.0`.